# Is it possible to cleanup in a node.js module, before Vite is page reloading on file change?

Tags: node.js, vite

I'm developing a node.js application, using Sveltekit + vite.

I have a file, where I attach event-listeners.

When I change the specific file, a new listener is attached but the old one is still active.

Is it possible somehow to hook into the Vite page reload life-cycle?

I currently tried to listen for `proceess.on('SIGINT|'SIGTERM'|'SIGHUP')`, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you can write a plugin to hook on `handleHotUpdate`.

Look at the following small plugin example :

`custom-hot.ts` :

```
/**
 * Custom Hot Reloading Plugin
 */

const data = 1337

export default function CustomHot() {
    return {
        name: 'custom-hot',
        enforce: 'post',
        handleHotUpdate({ file, server }) {

            console.log('> custom hot update', 'HotUpdate Hook')
            
            server.ws.send({
                type: 'custom',
                event: 'custom-hot',
                data: {"dummyData": data}
            })

            console.log('> Look at websockets messages for the event then look at your developer console to see the message from `hmr.ts`...', 'HotUpdate Hook')
        }
```

`vite.config.ts`:

```
[...]

plugins: [
  customHot()
],

[...]
```

`hmr.ts`

```
/**
 * Customized HMR module
 * eg: could be used to keep safe stores values with svelte/store
 */ 
 
if (import.meta && import.meta.hot) {
  import.meta.hot.accept()
  import.meta.hot.on('custom-hot', (data) => {
      console.log('received event with data: ' , data)
  })  
}
```

Now to see the result, save the module file `hmr.ts` and then :

- a `custom event` with `custom data` is fired through `websockets`:

[image]

- once received, you can see a message log on the developer tool:

[image]

For more information, head to the offical doc at

- https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-hmr.html#hot-accept-cb
- https://vitejs.dev/guide/api-plugin.html#handlehotupdate

Comment: And then the server would then `listen` for this with `import.meta.hot`?

Comment: I've added the `customHot` plugin, works like a charm. I get the output to the console, and use the `server.ws.send()` function. But in my client code, I **never** reach `if (import.meta.hot)`

Comment: What is your version of vite/svelte and vite-plugin-svelte if it exists on package.json ?

Comment: Vite is the only one (we are using sveltekit), and the version of vite is`2.3.0`

Comment: @DauleDK sorry for the delay, I updated the answer so you can get a full working example.

Comment: thanks for expanding the answer. Works great in the browser - if I add the above code to for example layot.svelte, it works, and I get notified about hot reload. But it does *not* work when used in a ts module, called from `index.hooks`. (in my example, I listen for a mongodb change stream, started from the hooks file)