# Transform, generate and serve dynamic content with Vite

Tags: vite

I was wondering if any of the following is possible to implement using `vite` build tool.

Consider that I have files in directory matching the pattern: `/content/file-[id].md`

- /content/file-1.md
- /content/file-2.md

Every time I serve the SPA app with `vite` command or building an app with `vite build` I would like to

1. grab all the files `/content/file-[id].md` and transform them into `/content_parsed/file-[id].html`

- /content_parsed/file-1.html
- /content_parsed/file-2.html

2. grab all files `/content_parsed/file-[id].html` and generated a manifest file `/files.manifest` containing all paths of files.

- /files.manifest

This has to be done automatically in **watch mode**, when the app is served (`vite` command) and **on-demand** when app is built (`vite build`).

I am pretty sure this is possible to be done with a manual script that I could run with `node ./prepareFiles.js && vite`, but in this case I am loosing the **reactivity** when serving the app (i.e. the watch-mode).. so a direct integration into `vite` would be a step-up in terms of usability and testability (I think).

Given the above use-case - can `vite` do this? Do I need to write a custom plugin for that? or do you recommend creating a separate watch-files/watch-directory script for that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? I don't get the point 1. It seem to me you are overcomplicating things but i can be wrong - could you elaborate or publish a reproducible project ? (give a look at @mdx-js/rollup package)

Comment: I am planning on generating a "blog like" SPA website in `vue.js`. The blog posts are to be written in `markdown`. Hence this is why all the example pages in `content` directory have an `.md` extension. In a typical blog you have to know in advance a full list of posts to render the list of post previews. This is where `files.manifest` is required. It will contain a full list of blog posts. The vue app will then read the manifest file and render this list accordingly. `Vite` is the build tool used nowadays by `vuejs`/`react` etc this is why I scoped the question specifically to `vite`.

Comment: At this point I am still prototyping the overall solution since there are many things I will need to solve, including the SSG (pre-rendering). There is no solution or the source code I could share at this moment. I will either update the question later when I have something to share, or, I might as well provide the answer to my own question if I am able to resolve it using vite-plugin system.. (in actuality I will also be using the `cloudflare workers` to serve the site and `netlify CMS` to generate markdown documents. this is why planning might take a couple of days.)

Comment: I see, to give you an idea, you should try `vite-plugin-md` from antfu and then just load dynamically the `md` files from folder with `vite-plugin-pages`.  md files are not required to be transformed to html if your project doesn't require it. I will make a demo later.

Comment: @flydev hey! Small update from me. I have managed to implement 90% of what I wanted except the hot-reload functionality.. I have looked into the plugin you suggested and it looks like it would only make sense to use it together with `vite-plugin-pages`.. I think this is a complementary solution that I will use in addition to my own solution later. I do still need to have a manifest files that contains metadata from all markdown documents regardless.. Thank you for the input on this topic! (p.s. you will find my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to partially accomplish what I wanted. The only issue right now is the hot reload functionality.

If you import the manifest as `import doc from 'docs.json'` then the page will be auto-reloaded if the module is updated.

On the other hand, if you want to dynamically load the data with `fetch` API:

```js
    fetch('docs.json')
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(json => {
          //...
        })
```

Then, the only way to refresh the page contents is by manual refresh. If anyone has a suggestion how to trigger reload from within `vite plugin` context please let me know. I will update the post once I figure it out.

Also I should mention that I have decided not to pre-generate the `html` pages so this functionality is missing from the plugin but could easily be extended with `marked`, `markdown-it` `remarked` etc.

Plugin: `generateFilesManifest.ts`

```js
import {PluginOption} from "vite";

import fs from "fs";
import path from 'path'

const matter = require('front-matter');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
import {FSWatcher} from "chokidar";

export type GenerateFilesManifestConfigType = {
    watchDirectory: string,
    output: string
}

export type MatterOutputType<T> = {
    attributes: T,
    body: string,
    bodyBegin: number,
    frontmatter: string,
    path: string,
    filename: string,
    filenameNoExt: string,
}

export default function generateFilesManifest(userConfig: GenerateFilesManifestConfigType): PluginOption {
    let config: GenerateFilesManifestConfigType = userConfig
    let rootDir: string
    let publicDir: string
    let command: string

    function generateManifest() {
        const watchDirFullPath = path.join(rootDir, config.watchDirectory)
        const files = fs.readdirSync(watchDirFullPath);

        // regenerate manifest
        const manifest: any[] = []
        files.forEach(fileName => {
            const fileFullPath = path.join(watchDirFullPath, fileName)

            // get front matter data
            const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fileFullPath).toString()
            //const frontMatter = matter.read(fileFullPath)
            const frontMatter = matter(fileContents)
            //console.log(frontMatter);

            // get file path relative to public directory
            //const basename = path.basename(__dirname)
            const fileRelativePath = path.relative(publicDir, fileFullPath);

            const fileInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(frontMatter)) as MatterOutputType<any>;
            fileInfo.path = fileRelativePath
            fileInfo.filename = fileName
            fileInfo.filenameNoExt = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
            fileInfo.frontmatter = ''

            manifest.push(fileInfo);
        });

        const outputString = JSON.stringify(manifest, null, 2);
        fs.writeFileSync(config.output, outputString, {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'w'})
        console.log('Auto-generated file updated')
    }

    let watcher: FSWatcher | undefined = undefined;

    return {
        name: 'generate-files-manifest',

        configResolved(resolvedConfig) {
            publicDir = resolvedConfig.publicDir
            rootDir = resolvedConfig.root
            command = resolvedConfig.command
        },

        buildStart(options: NormalizedInputOptions) {
            generateManifest();

            if (command === 'serve') {
                const watchDirFullPath = path.join(rootDir, config.watchDirectory)
                watcher = chokidar.watch(watchDirFullPath,
                    {
                        ignoreInitial: true
                    }
                );

                watcher
                    .on('add', function (path) {
                        //console.log('File', path, 'has been added');
                        generateManifest();
                    })
                    .on('change', function (path) {
                        //console.log('File', path, 'has been changed');
                        generateManifest();
                    })
                    .on('unlink', function (path) {
                        //console.log('File', path, 'has been removed');
                        generateManifest();
                    })
                    .on('error', function (error) {
                        console.error('Error happened', error);
                    })
            }
        },

        buildEnd(err?: Error) {
            console.log('build end')
            watcher?.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In `vite.config.ts`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        generateFilesManifest({
            watchDirectory: '/public/docs',
            output: './public/docs.json'
        })
    ]
})
```

You might want to cover such as edge-cases as watch directory not present, etc.

`front-matter` is the library that parses markdown files. An alternative is `gray-matter`.

**EDIT:** Thanks to @flydev response I was able to dig some more examples on page reload functionality. Here's the **experimental** functionality that you could add:

```js
    function generateManifest() {
        // ...

        ws?.send({type: 'full-reload', path: '*'})
    }

    let ws: WebSocketServer | undefined = undefined;

    return {
        name: 'generate-files-manifest',

        //...

        configureServer(server: ViteDevServer) {
            ws = server.ws
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Currently the whole page is reloaded regardless of the path. Not sure if there is a way to make it smart enough to just reload pages that loaded the manifest file. I guess it's currently limited by my own ability to write a better code  :)

Comment: good! Alex, you can write a custom plugin to handle custom `hmr` event, you could take inspiration from my other answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69632090/774432 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/69626090/774432

Comment: @flydev check out the edit :) now it's 95% finished. 5% are reserved for the smarter reload functionality. p.s. HMR is hard. I tried invoking `import.meta.hot.invalidate()` but it raises all kinds of issues for me. a bunch of compile errors to say the least.. not sure if I am ready to spend days on making a better solution, checking how the HMR API works. I wish there were more examples I could learn from (copy) :)

Comment: @flydev do you know where I could read more about `full-reload` command, how it works, and what are the other options available? Doesn't seem like google knows of anything when searching 'vite "full-reload"'

Comment: you should be able to achieve it by sending a custom event instead of the full-reload and writing logic inside import.meta.hot.on('custom-event-foo') listener. Check another answer with an example there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68861082/774432 and the second answer of the second link previously given.